# Wrong output in appending items to a dictionary of dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this empty `dictionary of dictionary` in `python` and I am trying to append/add items to it. The individual inner dictionary itself has list as its value for key.

The empty structure of my dict of dict is:

```
grp_task_text_dict = {'Group 1': {}, 'Group 2': {}}
```

Here is my current code which reads items and based on certain conditions, it needs to append that item to either `Group 1` or `Group 2`:

```
def text_mapping_bot2():

    group_list = ['Group 1','Group 2']
    task_text_dict = {}
    grp_task_text_dict = {i: task_text_dict for i in group_list}
    grp_mapping = {i: [] for i in group_list}

    print('EMPTY GROUP TASK TEXT DICT = {}'.format(grp_task_text_dict))

    bot_mapping = [{'Name': '', 'Task ID': '0','Task Text': 'Try again!', 'Group': '', 'Complementary Action': ''}, {'Name': 'Hello', 'Task ID': '1.0','Task Text': 'Hi, Welcome', 'Group': 'Group 2', 'Complementary Action': 'group'}, {'Name': 'Hello', 'Task ID': '11.0', 'Task Text': 'Tell me about car options? ', 'Group': 'Group 2', 'Complementary Action': ''}, {'Bot Name': 'Hello', 'Task ID': '11.0', 'Task Text': 'What are different car options?', 'Group': 'Group 2', 'Complementary Action': ''}, {'Name': 'Hello', 'Task ID': '11.0','Task Text': 'What cars are there?', 'Group': 'Group 2','Complementary Action': ''}, {'Name': 'Hello', 'Task ID': '11.0','Task Text': 'May I know about Car types?', 'Group': 'Group 2','Complementary Action': ''}, {'Name': 'Hello', 'Task ID': '2.0', 'Task Text': 'How much is the rent of compact car? ', 'Group': 'Group 2','Complementary Action': ''}, {'Name': 'Hello', 'Task ID': '2.0','Task Text': 'Compact car expenses?', 'Group': 'Group 2', 'Complementary Action': ''}, {'Name': 'Hello', 'Task ID': '2.0', 'Task Text': 'Cost of compact car?', 'Group': 'Group 2', 'Complementary Action': ''}, {'Name': 'Hello', 'Task ID': '2.0','Task Text': 'How much do I need to pay for small car', 'Group': 'Group 2', 'Complementary Action': ''}]

    for item in bot_mapping:
        print("ITEM IN BOT MAPPING = {}".format(item))
        print('\n')
        print('\n')

        for grp, val in grp_task_text_dict.items():
            print('CURRENT VAL = {} and GROUP = {}'.format(val, grp))
            try:
                if last_id < int(float(item['Task ID'])):
                    last_id = int(float(item['Task ID']))
            except:
                pass
            try:
                if item['Task ID'] == '':
                    item['Task ID'] = '0'
                if (item['Task ID'] in val) and (str(item['Group']).lower() == str(grp).lower()):

                    print('\n')

                    print('CURRENT STATUS OF GROUP TASK TEXT DICT BEFORE APPENDING= {}'.format(
                        grp_task_text_dict))
                    print('\n')

                    print('GROUP AND TASK ID ALREADY IN ITEM AND TASK TEXT DICT IS SAME - {} and {}'.format(
                        str(item['Group']).lower(), str(grp).lower()))
                    print('\n')

                    print('APPENDING TO THIS GROUP IN GRP TASK DICT = {}'.format(grp_task_text_dict[grp][item['Task ID']]))

                    # val[item['Task ID']].append(item['Task Text'])
                    grp_task_text_dict[grp][item['Task ID']].append(item['Task Text'])
                    print('CURRENT STATUS OF GROUP TASK TEXT DICT AFTER APPENDING= {}. Going to Break out of loop'.format(
                        grp_task_text_dict))
                    break
                elif str(item['Group']).lower() == str(grp).lower():
                    print('CURRENT STATUS OF GROUP TASK TEXT DICT BEFORE APPENDING IN NEW TASK ID= {}'.format(
                        grp_task_text_dict))
                    print('\n')
                    print('NEW TASK ID BUT GROUP SAME = {} and {}'.format(str(item['Group']).lower(), str(grp).lower()))
                    print('\n')

                    print('APPENDING TO THIS GROUP IN GRP TASK DICT IN NEW ID = {}'.format(grp_task_text_dict[grp]))
                    print('\n')

                    # val[item['Task ID']] = [item['Task Text']]
                    grp_task_text_dict[grp][item['Task ID']] = [item['Task Text']]
                    print(
                        'CURRENT STATUS OF GROUP TASK TEXT DICT AFTER APPENDING IN NEW TASK ID = {}. Going to Break out of loop'.format(
                            grp_task_text_dict))
                    break
            except Exception as e:
                print("THIS EXCEPTION CAME = {}".format(e))
                # print('--iteration check--', task_text_dict)
```

What I want is that based on `Group` filed in each `item` in `bot_mapping`, the code should either append it to the list associated with `Task ID` of that group dictionary in grp_task_text_dict if the `Task ID` is already existing in that group dictionary, or create a new list with new `Task ID` within the matching group dictionary in `grp_task_text_dict`. So for example if `Group` in item is `Group 2` and `Task ID` is `11.0` then this item should be appended to list of `Task ID` `11.0` in `Group 2` dictionary of `grp_task_text_dict` and not in `Group 1`.

When I execute this code it appends the item to both `Group 1` and `Group 2` dictionaries even though my code is appending to specific group using `grp_task_text_dict[grp][item['Task ID']].append(item['Task Text'])` after matching the `Group` name using `if (item['Task ID'] in val) and (str(item['Group']).lower() == str(grp).lower()):`.

A sample output of my code looks like this:

```
ITEM IN BOT MAPPING = {'Bot Name': 'Hello', 'Task ID': '11.0', 'Task Text': 'What are different car options?', 'Group': 'Group 2', 'Complementary Action': ''}




CURRENT VAL = {'1.0': ['Hi, Welcome'], '11.0': ['Tell me about car options? ']} and GROUP = Group 1
CURRENT VAL = {'1.0': ['Hi, Welcome'], '11.0': ['Tell me about car options? ']} and GROUP = Group 2


CURRENT STATUS OF GROUP TASK TEXT DICT BEFORE APPENDING= {'Group 1': {'1.0': ['Hi, Welcome'], '11.0': ['Tell me about car options? ']}, 'Group 2': {'1.0': ['Hi, Welcome'], '11.0': ['Tell me about car options? ']}}


GROUP AND TASK ID ALREADY IN ITEM AND TASK TEXT DICT IS SAME - group 2 and group 2


APPENDING TO THIS GROUP IN GRP TASK DICT = ['Tell me about car options? ']
CURRENT STATUS OF GROUP TASK TEXT DICT AFTER APPENDING= {'Group 1': {'1.0': ['Hi, Welcome'], '11.0': ['Tell me about car options? ', 'What are different car options?']}, 'Group 2': {'1.0': ['Hi, Welcome'], '11.0': ['Tell me about car options? ', 'What are different car options?']}}
```

As you can see above it is appending to both `Group 1` and `Group 2` when it should only append to `Group 2`.

I know there is some error in my logic but I am unable to figure out what and where the issue is which is causing this wrong output. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
grp_task_text_dict = {i: task_text_dict for i in group_list}
```

This makes all the elements in this dictionary refer to the same `task_text_dict` dictionary, they don't get copies. Change it to:

```
grp_task_text_dict = {i: {} for i in group_list}
```

Then it will initialize each dictionary element with its own empty dictionary.